# Validation for email id using firstname and lastname with + sign between in android

Tags: android

I want to validate these two patterns for email id in andorid but not getting anything please help if someone knows:

```
1) Firstname+Lastname@abc.com
2) Firstname.Lastname+1@abc.com.
```

even i tried many validation patterns given below:

```
 1) String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

 2) String EMAIL_PATTERN ="[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
            "\\@" +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1,64}" +
            "(" +
            "\\." +
            "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{1,25}" +
            ")+" ;
 3) String EMAIL_PATTERN =  "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
 4) String EMAIL_PATTERN ="/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s_]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/";

 5)public final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9+._%-+]{1,256}" + "@"
                    + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}" + "(" + "."
                    + "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25}" + ")+");
```

Comment: all email id's are working but when i used the two above i mentioned i got invalid email id that i showed on validating the email id but i want a pattern that can validate the above two types too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this : following code is working for me
```

//IN afterTextChanged(Editable s)

```
    if (!new EmailValidator().validate(edt.getText().toString())) {
        int ecolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
        String estring = "someone@example.com";  // your error message
        ForegroundColorSpan fgcspan = new ForegroundColorSpan(ecolor);
        SpannableStringBuilder ssbuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(estring);
        ssbuilder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, estring.length(), 0);

        mEmail.setError(ssbuilder);
    }
```

public class EmailValidator {

```
private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN =   "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
       "\\@" +
       "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
       "(" +
       "\\." +
       "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
       ")+";



public EmailValidator() {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
}

/**
 * Validate hex with regular expression
 *
 * @param hex
 *            hex for validation
 * @return true valid hex, false invalid hex
 */
public boolean validate(final String hex) {

    matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
    return matcher.matches();

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot i even tried this but there was problem from my side but this works.

Comment: Ok Thank you.All the best